# error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '.' token?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm writing a program in C with structs and pointers etc.
However, when I run it, it gives this error: *"error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '.' token"*

at the following line

```
char *strcpy(char *account[i].nome, const char *nomi[p]);
```

Basically what I wanna do is, assing a random name taken from char nomi[p] where p is a random index between 0 and 4 into account.nome[i] variable where [i] is decleared in the for loop.

As you can see I commented this line

```
//account[i].nome = nomi[p];
```

Otherwise it would have gave me this error -> error: assignment to expression with array type

Any hints?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // includo la libreria per gestire le funzioni sui caratteri

#define MAX_ACCOUNT 5
#define MAX_NOME 20
#define MAX_COGNOME 20
#define MAX_EMAIL 40

typedef struct {
  int giorno;
  int mese;
  int anno;
} data;

typedef struct {
  char nome[MAX_NOME];
  char cognome[MAX_COGNOME];
  data datadinascita;
  char email[MAX_EMAIL];
  char password;
} acc;

int main(void) {

  int seed = time(NULL); //     Randomizzo
  srand(seed);           //     time
  unsigned i = 0;
  unsigned p = 0;
  unsigned q = 0;
  unsigned r = 0;
  char* nomi[4] = {"Gianmarco","Francesco","Michele","Marco","Roberto"};
  char* cognomi[4] = {"Lorusso","Simone","Caggiano","Moramarco","Colonna"};
  char* email[4] = {"rymmysice-2084@gmail.com","junetome-4060@hotmail.com","ikijaza-9272@live.it","hokalife-2155@libero.it","ottejotto-2395@gmail.com"};

  acc account[MAX_ACCOUNT] = {0};
  data datadinascita[MAX_ACCOUNT]; //variabile datadinascita


  //Ciclo di lettura
  for(i = 0; i < MAX_ACCOUNT; i++) {

    p = rand() % (4-0+1) + 0; //Max 4, Min 0
    q = rand() % (4-0+1) + 0; //Max 4, Min 0
    r = rand() % (4-0+1) + 0; //Max 4, Min 0

    char *strcpy(char *account[i].nome, const char *nomi[p]);
    //account[i].nome = nomi[p];
    //account[i].cognome = *cognomi[q];
    datadinascita[i].giorno = rand() % (31-1+1) + 1; //Max 31, Min 1
    datadinascita[i].mese = rand() % (12-1+1) + 1; //Max 12, Min 1
    datadinascita[i].anno = rand() % (2003-1960+1) + 1960; //Max 2003, Min 1960
    //account[i].email = *email[r];

    printf("ACCOUNT #%d: ", i+1);
    printf("Prova");
    printf("\n\tNome: %19s", account[i].nome);
    printf("\n\tCognome: %19s", account[i].cognome);
    printf("\n\tData di nascita: %d-%d-%d", datadinascita[i].giorno, datadinascita[i].mese, datadinascita[i].anno);
    printf("\n\tEmail: %39s", account[i].email);
    printf("\n");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *strcpy(char *account[i].nome, const char *nomi[p]);` is not a function *call*.

Comment: Change `char *strcpy(char *account[i].nome, const char *nomi[p]);` to `strcpy(account[i].nome, nomi[p]);` and add `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <time.h>`. You are also trying to provide 5 initialisers to your 4-element arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like

```
strcpy(account[i].nome, nomi[p]);
```

Comment: This and the reply from @Weather Vane perfectly worked.

Comment: @SlimShadys Now the big question for you: Do you understand why? And I'm curious, where did the previous line come from? Was it a copy-paste that you didn't modify correctly?